# SQL SSMS merge IDs into row grouping by dates

Tags: sql, ssms

I have two tables:

**Main table**

| ID | Date | Device |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 252708 | 2022-01-01 | Phone |
| 252708 | 2022-01-01 | Email |
| 252252 | 2022-01-02 | Phone |
| 252252 | 2022-01-02 | Phone |
| 252252 | 2022-01-02 | Phone |
| 253022 | 2022-01-06 | Phone |
| 253022 | 2022-01-06 | Phone |
| 253228 | 2022-01-06 | Email |
| 253228 | 2022-01-06 | Email |
| 252708 | 2022-01-06 | Phone |
| 256703 | 2022-01-09 | Phone |

**Date table**

| Date | Week |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | WK 17 |
| 2022-01-02 | WK 18 |
| 2022-01-03 | WK 18 |
| 2022-01-04 | WK 18 |
| 2022-01-05 | WK 18 |
| 2022-01-06 | WK 18 |
| 2022-01-07 | WK 18 |
| 2022-01-08 | WK 18 |
| 2022-01-09 | WK 19 |
| 2022-01-10 | WK 19 |
| 2022-01-11 | WK 19 |

I want to merge the IDs into rows, grouping by Wk (using my date table)

| ID | Date | Device_1 | Wk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 252708 | 2022-01-01 | Phone, Email | WK17 |
| 252252 | 2022-01-02 | Phone, Phone, Phone | WK18 |
| 253022 | 2022-01-06 | Phone, Phone | WK18 |
| 253228 | 2022-01-06 | Email, Email | WK18 |
| 252708 | 2022-01-06 | Phone | WK18 |
| 256703 | 2022-01-09 | Phone | WK19 |

I know I need the `string_agg` function to merge the devices into rows, however, I'm not sure how to separate by week. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use "FOR XML" instead of STRING_AGG.  It would be something like this:

```
select 
    distinct(dev.ID)
    ,dev.Date
    ,(
        select  
            Device + ',' as [text()]
        FROM MainTable a
        JOIN DateTable b on a.Date = b.Date
        Where dev.ID = a.ID and b.Week = cal.Week
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ) as Device_1
    ,cal.Week
FROM MainTable dev
JOIN DateTable cal on dev.Date = cal.Date
Order By Week
```

Comment: Welcome! You may want to explore the string_agg function though as it might be a bit easier to read and implement. Only downside is It's a newer feature so it's not available in most SQL versions.